# Symfony and replacing many $entity->setXyz($entity->getXyz)

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony

I have many of these:

```
$test->setName($something->getName());
$test->setAge($something->getAge());
// ...
```

and I want to clean up my code, so I have decided to wrote a simple foreach, like this:

```
$fields = array('Age','Name','Address','City', ... );
foreach($fields as $f) {
       $test->{'set'.$f}($something->{'get'.$f.'()'});
}
```

but it gives me an error:

Notice: Undefined property: TestBundle\Entity\Test::$getAge()

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parenthesis is not string, try it,

```
$test->{'set'.$f}($something->{'get'.$f}());
```